# git repo up-to-date but it is really not

Tags: git, github

I committed this morning on my own pc at home. And now I am using an university pc. I tried git pull and git merge but nothing happened. It says up-to-date but it is really not.

So the origin branch(which can be viewed online), also is the parent branch to the branch on this university pc. It has been changed after the branch on this pc committed last time, right? So the git pull should work?

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Did you `git push` after you did `git commit`?

Comment: Can you see the changes you have made on the Github repos commit list?

Comment: My psychic powers suggest you forgot to do the `git push`

Comment: @Raizuri Yes I did commit and push.

Comment: @selbie lol I remembered I should did commit and push tho. Should I be tired and forgot to do so?

Comment: If you're working on different branches, try going through all the usual checks: `git fetch` to get all branches for the repo, `git merge` if needed.

Comment: @Raizuri I did git fetch and nothing happened. I just tried git merge and it said Already up-to-date.

Comment: @LukeGlazebrook Yes I did git log and I can see my commit this morning

Answer (score 1):

You can use the git `log` to view the commits in your repository.  This will allow you to see if the commits that you think were `push`ed truly were

```
$ git fetch # Make sure you're up to date with the remote
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all -20
```

That will show you the last 20 commits made to your repository.  You said that the "parent" branch has been changed since the last time you worked on the university PC; if that's the case, you should be able to see those commits in the log output.

If you see the commit that you're looking for, you can run the following to `reset` your working directory to that same code.  Find that commit in the log and copy it's SHA hash.

```
# WARNING: Make sure that 'git status' is empty before doing this
#          or you will lose your work
$ git reset --hard <sha-of-commit-you-want>
```

If you don't see the commit, and there's the possibility that it's older than 20 commits ago, you can run the `log` command again with a bigger number at the end (or no number at all).  If you still don't see it, it sounds like you didn't successfully `push` from your home PC.

Answer (score 0):

My spider-sense tells me that you forgot to do `git push` :)